# Ссылка на комментарий php/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-5.8

Подскажите,как сделать ссылку на комментарий к статье как [здесь](https://fishki.net/3114513-chej-borw-vkusnye-istorii-ot-shef-povara-anons-prjamogo-jefira-na-fishkinet.html/comment-35911630/)

когда переходим на сайт, чтобы выделялся комментарий и страница опустилась к нему?

Answer (score 1):

Выводишь блок с комментарием:

```
<div class='...' id="{{$comment->id}}">Тут коммент</div>
```

Дальше где-то, или в комменте или в блоке или уже за блоком, как вы там себе думаете, помещаете ссылку типа:

```
   <a href="/post/post_id/comment/comment_id">Ссылка</a>
```

А дальше уже в шаблон передаете переменную с контроллера нарпимер `$comment_id`, которая будет хранить ид комеента

И уже в блоке с комментом смотрите

```
 <div class="@if($comment_id === $comment->id) active @endif" id="{{$comment->id}}">Тут коммент</div>
```

Ну и в css файле нужно прописать стили и подключить его, например

```
.active{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

И у вас будет точно так же как на том сайте

А вообще - это лучше сделать с JQuery или Ajax и т.д...